# CASE expression ent returning ELSE value for every account even when condition is True

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

The below query returns two rows for every account with both the 'Active' and 'Inactive' labels even when the CASE expression logic is True.

ex.
If an account has 'revenue' greater than 0 and the fiscal_qtr = '2022-Q1' instead of returning just 'Active' it also returns a row with the value 'Inactive'.

```
SELECT 
geo,
account,
subsegment,
forecast_group,
CASE 
WHEN revenue > 0 and fiscal_qtr = '2022-Q1' then 'Active'
ELSE 'Inactive'
END AS "Active Acct"
FROM rev_planning.ace_global
WHERE
(fiscal_year_num between 2018 and 2021 or fiscal_qtr = '2022-Q1')
and revenue > 0
GROUP BY geo, account, subsegment, forecast_group
```

I have tried putting the case expression in parenthesis but it still returns two rows for all of the accounts that should just be returning 'Active'

```
(WHEN revenue > 0 and fiscal_qtr = '2022-Q1' then 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive'END) AS "Active Acct"
```

Current Output

| geo | account | subsegment | forecast group | acitveacct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APAC | brothers neilsen | australia | dbiq | Active |
| APAC | brothers neilsen | australia | dbiq | Inactive |

Expected Output (because brothers neilsen should be "Active" based on the case expression

| geo | account | subsegment | forecast group | acitveacct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APAC | brothers neilsen | australia | dbiq | Active |

Comment: Why the GROUP BY? Do you simply want SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Show us some sample table data, the current result and the wanted result - all as formatted text (no images, no links.) Simplify if possible -  [mcve]!

Comment: It might be work with "DISTINCT" wordkey. Another way is to include CASE block in the end of GROUP BY block. We need some table data including table definition to solve your question more faster.

Comment: The `group by` is unnecessary. If you run your query without the `case` how many rows do you retrieve ?

Comment: I have removed the group by because as you said it is not useful. When I remove the case I get a large number of rows per account, which I suspect is related to the WHERE clause returning a row for each year.

Comment: add sample data to reproduce the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried putting the case expression in parenthesis but it still
> returns two rows for all of the accounts that should just be returning
> 'Active'

That's what should happen if the SELECT returns rows for multiple years and quarters. Due to the CASE the current year and quarter (2022-Q1) would be considered *'Active'* and prior years would be *'Inactive'*.

It sounds like you only want to return the most recent year. Try using [ROW_NUMBER()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) to sort and rank the fiscal quarters for each account. Then use `where RowNum = 1` to grab the most recent one. The query below partitions results by `geo, account, subsegment`, but you can adjust it as needed:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT * 
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
             PARTITION BY geo, account, subsegment 
             ORDER BY fiscal_year_num DESC, fiscal_qtr DESC
          ) AS RowNum
   FROM   ace_global
   WHERE  revenue > 0
   OR   ( fiscal_year_num BETWEEN 2018 AND 2021
           OR fiscal_qtr = '2022-Q1'
        )
)
SELECT geo
      , account
      , subsegment
      , forecast_group
      , CASE WHEN fiscal_qtr = '2022-Q1' THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END AS "Active Acct" 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  RowNum = 1
```

**Sample Data**

> ```
> geo | account     | subsegment | forecast_group | revenue | fiscal_year_num | fiscal_qtr
> :-- | :---------- | :--------- | :------------- | ------: | --------------: | :---------
> ABC | abc company | australia  | dbiq           |   50000 |            2018 | 2018-Q1   
> ABC | abc company | australia  | dbiq           | 1000000 |            2022 | 2022-Q1   
> EFG | efg company | australia  | dbiq           |   75000 |            2020 | 2020-Q2   
> HIJ | hij company | australia  | dbiq           |  787000 |            2021 | 2021-Q3   
> HIJ | hij company | australia  | dbiq           | 2000000 |            2022 | 2022-Q1
> ```

**Results:**

> ```
> geo | account     | subsegment | forecast_group | Active Acct
> :-- | :---------- | :--------- | :------------- | :----------
> ABC | abc company | australia  | dbiq           | Active     
> EFG | efg company | australia  | dbiq           | Inactive   
> HIJ | hij company | australia  | dbiq           | Active
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9f447a3e2437252ec8ad91ec0551f698)*